# Selenium Java findElement Query not valid for unique ID or Xpath

Tags: java, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I am trying to select the email, password, and signin elements from [here](https://www.zoho.com/crm/lp/login.html).

The element has a unique ID and I'm able to copy the Xpath from inspecting it.

I have tried these queries and unable to figure out why Selenium cannot find it.

```
    WebElement emailfield = driver.findElement(By.id("lid"))

    WebElement emailfield = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'lid\']"));

    WebElement emailfield = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=lid]"));
```

The drive is able to open and launch chrome to do this. However, I am not lucky.
Please let me know in what way these are not valid. As I understand it, the id should be completely unique but neither the By.id and By.xpath methods are not finding the element.

Here is my code.

```
    String email = "myemail";
    String password = "the_password";
    WebElement emailfield = driver.findElement(By.id("lid"));
    emailfield.sendKeys(email );
    WebElement passwordfield = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=pwd]"));
    passwordfield.sendKeys(password );

    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("submit_but"));
    login.click();
```

Here is HTML table.

```
  <table width="260" align="center" class="mob_width" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1">

                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                        <h3 class="signintxt">Sign In</h3> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="2"><span id="msgpanel"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td class="label">Email / Phone:</td>
                       <td align="left"><input name="lid" class="input usrbx" id="lid" onkeypress="clearmsg()" type="email" value=""></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="label">Password:</td>
                    <td align="left"><input name="pwd" class="input passbx" id="pwd" onkeypress="clearmsg()" type="password"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td class="label"></td>
                    <td align="left"><div class="forgotpasslink"><span onclick="goToForgotPassword();">Forgot Password?</span></div>
                    </td></tr>

                    <tr id="hiptr" style="display: none;">
                                            <td class="label">&nbsp;</td><td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="emptytd"></td>
                    <td height="30" class="mobile-height">


                    <div class="sectxt">
                        <label>
                            <input name="rem" id="rem" type="checkbox" value="10">
                            <span class="securetxt">Keep me signed in</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>


                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="emptytd"></td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <button name="submit" class="submit_mobile" id="submit_but" type="submit">Sign In</button>


                    </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody></table>
```

Here is an Explicit wait that compiles, and wait 10 seconds and gives same error.

```
    //explicit
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement aboutMe;
    aboutMe= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//form[@id='login']//*[@id='lid']")));
    aboutMe.click();
```

Comment: Please post the HTML source part where that element exists. I see no reason why it cannot be found from the Java source code.

Comment: Check post, I added the table on the page.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//form[@id='login']//*[@id='lid']"}

Comment: If I target all elements through ID or Xpath, it can't target everything. I throught it might be because I just downloaded selenium but it at least opens the driver and is able to go to a page.

Comment: Dom Element: <input type="email" name="lid" id="lid" class="input usrbx" value="" onkeypress="clearmsg()">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields are inside `<iframe>`. You need to switch to it first

```
driver.switchTo.frame("zohoiam"); // switch by iframe ID

WebElement emailfield = driver.findElement(By.id("lid"));
// some more code

driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // switch out of the iframe
```

For more switch options look [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html).

Comment: Hey! This worked here. I didn't catch this nor realize this was a problem. How can you tell?

Comment: @JakeGoss-Kuehn Right click on the field and choose "Inspect" from the menu, it will open the html tree with the element. From there you can move up the html tree and see there is an `<iframe>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have made syntactical error while writing the xpath,

```
//*[@id=\'lid\']
```

has wrong syntax [You can verify this using firebug & firepath].

Try below xpath it should work,

```
.//*[@id='lid']
```

However you can add the parent Form node to make it more robust,

```
.//form[@id='login']//*[@id='lid']
```

***Finally, you need to make sure that you wait till the page is loaded completely before going for element identification.***

For more on explicit wait, refer [Selenium webdriver explicit wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077860/selenium-webdriver-explicit-wait)

Comment: I have given it a wait of 10 seconds before timing out, but not one of those three solutions worked.

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: You should go for explicit wait instead of implicit one. Give some conditions to check before moving to next action. I have updated my answer with reference to explicit wait.